# Cmake command line arguments vs add_compile_definitions

Tags: cmake

what is the difference between compiling with `cmake .. -DVAR="something"` and `cmake ..` but using `add_compile_definitions(VAR="something")` in CMakeLists.txt? How to achieve the same behavior as in command line argument but using CMakeLists.txt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what is the difference between compiling with cmake .. -DVAR="something" and cmake .. but using add_compile_definitions(VAR="something") in CMakeLists.txt?

The [cmake](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html) command line `-D` option does: "Create or update a CMake CACHE entry". The `-DVAR=something` set's `cmake` variable `VAR` to `something`.

[add_compile_definitions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_compile_definitions.html?highlight=add_compile_definitions#command:add_compile_definitions) does: "Add preprocessor definitions to the compilation of source files". In this case it adds a macro `VAR` to be set to `"something"` (I think including the quotes).

They do different things.

Prefer `target_compile_definitions` instead of `add_compile_definitions`.

> How to achieve the same behavior as in command line argument but using CMakeLists.txt?

If you want to set the cmake variable `VAR` to `something` do:

```
// in CMakeLists.txt
set(VAR something)
```

But this will not set the variable in cmake cache. The same behavior would be rather something along:

```
set(VAR something CACHE STRING "" FORCE)
```